# How does Struts create an action bean?

Tags: java, struts2, javabeans, ognl, struts2-interceptors

I use Struts2.x and I know that Struts creates the declared bean objects in the action based on the request so that it is available to the action. I have been researching to understand which interceptors/classes does Struts use internally to create the bean object. I am trying to understand the logic that is used internally for creation of the bean objects. Does it use `PropertyUtils` to populate properties for the beans or some other way? Any suggestion or pointers for reading will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Internally Struts uses the `ObjectFactory` to build all objects defined by the configuration. See more about [`ObjectFactory`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ObjectFactory.html) docs or [The Struts 2 Request Flow](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/The+Struts+2+Request+Flow).

When you populate some bean using [`params`](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) interceptor it will by default create objects if they not exist with the help of [OGNL](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/ognl). It's also configurable.

`PropertyUtils` isn't used by the Struts2 core, but could be used by plugins if they need a `commons-beanutils` package.

Comment: I see that [ObjectFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ObjectFactory.java/) has a method public Object buildBean(Class,Map<String,Object>), but this just returns a new Instance of the class. The [ParametersInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/parameters-interceptor.html) says that it sets action.setModelClass() based on the properties of action and also pushes the accepted params to valueStack, but I am still searching where the values from the Map are set into the created object.